# Scraping url and detect text parts

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I'd like to know if it's possible to scraping a specific url and detect all the text parts in it.

To be more specific , I'd like to scraping an article and find the title, the subtitle (if it exists) and the content. I know that in most articles there will be other noise-contents, like other suggested title, but I'll figure how to solve it out in the future. For now, I'm just asking how to scrape an url.
By reading in others Stack Overflow questions, I've found out that I can use ajax and jQuery to make it happen (like the little piece of code below, that I know is meaningless), but I'm not sure I've all the passages clear in my mind.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/thePageToScrape.html",
    dataType: 'text',
});
```

Comment: Better start by understanding `CORS` and `same origin policy` ... both are easy to research

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the suggestion! Always glad to learn new things. By the way, the problem is not so big: I've to scrape a "same origin" url.

Comment: can wrap the response in jQuery and use find() or other jQuery methods on it to get at what you want, then insert those parts in your page

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same-origin, you can use JQuery `$.get`

```
$.get("http://www.yourDomain.com/page=yourArticle", function (data) {
var title = $(data).find("#title").text();
});
```

Where the title of the article is in a div with id="title".

Comment: What if I want to find the words between <h1> tags? Or <p>?

Comment: @EmilianoNegri

`var h1 = $(data).find("h1").text();

var p =  $(data).find("p").text();`

For more information look at : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thats a large subject and better results will be achieved by doing it on the server side - but still here is a quick example:

Let say that we want this page: `var url = "http://someurl.com/scrapme1.html";`
And we want its content that looks like that:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ....
    </head>
<body>
      <h4 class='page-title'>
          I'm an article title
      </h4>
      <div class='summary'>
          ...
      </div>
      <div id="article_body">
          ...
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now we need The title (`h4.page-title`), the summary (`div.summary`) and the article content (`div#article_body`).

We can load the page into a jQuery element:

```
function getContent(url){
    var content = null;
    $.get('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx', 
        function(data) {
            var $dom = $(data); 
            var title = $dom.find("h4.page-title");
            var summary = $dom.find("div.summary");
            var article_body = $dom.find("div#article_body");
            //Do whatever you need....
        }
}
```

**More important notes**:

1. Obviously you need to make sure the expected data is returned correctly.
2. You can use `$.post(), .load(), .ajax()` too, and even add some POST variables.
3. Pages may have restricted origin policies so your requests may fail.
4. You can use some regex patterns to dynamically detect and synthesize some key values - such as publication date, author name etc.
5. You always need to have good knowledge on your source and use its elements selectors for better and quicker extraction of the relevant content.

Enjoy.